# wsdl error: HTTP ERROR: no data present after HTTP headers

Tags: http

when ever i m trying   to run the script i got an error of "wsdl error: HTTP ERROR: no data present after HTTP headers" can any bdy help me regarding it?

Comment: We're gonna need more information than this.  Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

This means that while the response contains headers (for example, a HTTP status code and content type) there is no data - i.e. no XML in the file.